# What do browsers do when a font weight is unavailable?

Tags: css, cross-browser, webfonts

If I load a google font that comes with 400 and 700 weights, but in my CSS I use `font-weight:550;` what does the browser do ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight) and [W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#propdef-font-weight):

> If the exact weight given is unavailable, then the following heuristic
>   is used to determine the weight actually rendered:
>
> - If a weight greater than 500 is given, the closest available darker weight is used (or, if there is none, the closest available lighter
>     weight).
> - If a weight less than 400 is given, the closest available lighter weight is used (or, if there is none, the closest available darker
>     weight).
> - If a weight of exactly 400 is given, then 500 is used. If 500 is not available, then the heuristic for font weights less than 500 is
>     used.
> - If a weight of exactly 500 is given, then 400 is used. If 400 is not available, then the heuristic for font weights less than 400 is
>     used.
>
> This means that for fonts that provide only normal and bold, 100-500 are normal, and 600-900 are bold.

Also:

> There is no guarantee that there will be a darker face for each of the
>   'font-weight' values; for example, some fonts may have only a normal
>   and a bold face, while others may have eight face weights. There is no
>   guarantee on how a UA will map font faces within a family to weight
>   values. The only guarantee is that a face of a given value will be no
>   less dark than the faces of lighter values.

Answer (score 2):

For the [`font-weight`](http://http:/http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#propdef-font-weight) property, the value `550` is invalid. According to CSS [error handling rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#parsing-errors), a declaration with an invalid value is ignored, i.e. the actual font weight is determined by other CSS rules (or falling back to defaults), as if the declaration were not there.